# Complicated PHP array logic

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I basically need to find a way to see which products were ordered the most, then return an array of the top 5 'post_id' s.

This is the array of different orders that contain product details:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [post_id] => 1
            [post_ident] => macbook_pro
            [post_name] => Macbook Pro
            [post_parent_ident] => rings
            [post_cat_ident] => default
            [post_module_ident] => store
            [post_price] => 999.00
            [post_currency] => EUR
            [item_link] => index.php?module=store&show=post&category=default&parent=rings&post=macbook_pro
            [qty] => 1
        )

)

Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [post_id] => 1
            [post_ident] => macbook_pro
            [post_name] => Macbook Pro
            [post_parent_ident] => rings
            [post_cat_ident] => default
            [post_module_ident] => store
            [post_price] => 999.00
            [post_currency] => EUR
            [item_link] => index.php?module=store&show=post&category=default&parent=rings&post=macbook_pro
            [qty] => 1
        )

)

Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [post_id] => 1
            [post_ident] => macbook_pro
            [post_name] => Macbook Pro
            [post_parent_ident] => rings
            [post_cat_ident] => default
            [post_module_ident] => store
            [post_price] => 999.00
            [post_currency] => EUR
            [item_link] => index.php?module=store&show=post&category=default&parent=rings&post=macbook_pro
            [qty] => 1
        )

)
```

How can I determine which products are in the array the most?

For example, the product with post_id 1 is in the array 3 times.  How would I count that, then return the post_id as the first item in the array?

Comment: Is that array coming from SQL?

Comment: No, the product details are serialized and this is the output after unserializing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$result = array();
foreach($array as $value)
{
   $postId = $value[1]['post_id'];
   if(isset($result[$postId])){
      $result[$postId]++;     // increment count of post id if already exists in result
   }
   else{
      $result[$postId] = 1;    // start count for post id
   }  
}

$keys = array_keys(asort($result));   // sort the array and find all the keys
echo $keys[count($keys)-1];           // last key will be the answer
```